# How to Filter out rows with specific string in R?

Tags: r

```
V1    V2
P1    1
P1    2
P1    3
P1    4
P1    2
P1    3
P1    4
P2    0
P2    3
P1    1
P3    1
P3    5
```

Hi all, I wanted to filter out rows from dataset B that contain P1 only (along with the variable V2) to a new table. I've tried

```
filter(str_detect(B$V1, "P1"))
```

and `B[grep("P1", rownames(B)), ]

and both doesn't work. It turned out to execute O obs. Thanks!
`

Comment: It's just `B[B$V1 == "P1", ]` if you're doing an exact match on a single value

Comment: or `dplyr::filter(B, V1 == "P1")` if you want to try `dplyr` and use `filter`

Comment: Thanks @RichardScriven. but it turned out to be 0 obs. :(

Comment: I don't see how it would be zero observations based on your example data.  I am getting 8 rows

Comment: Thank you @RichardScriven.was my mistake, now it works! :))

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
B[B$V1 == "P1", ]
```

and it will work perfectly!